# Playwright => Not all the page loading

Tags: python, playwright

I'm writing a Python script using playwright.
I would like to wait the complete loading of a page (for example https://meteofrance.com/) before taking the associated snapshot:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright

async def take_screenshot(url,filename):
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True, args=["--disable-features=site-per-process"])
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(url)
        await page.screenshot(path=filename, full_page=True)
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(take_screenshot("https://meteofrance.com/","screenshot.png"))
```

The result is:
https://ibb.co/r0xk00z

As you can see, not all the images are loaded.

I tried a timeout delay, `await page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")` and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason:

> Some elements work with lazy loading

So you need to emulate *user scrolling*. You can use [mouse.wheel()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-mouse#mouse-wheel) or [keyboard.press('PageDown')](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-keyboard#keyboard-press). Here is just an example:

```
# ...
await page.goto(url)

for _ in range(7):
    await page.keyboard.press('PageDown')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

await page.screenshot(path=filename, full_page=True)
await browser.close()
```